# Replacing blank character is not working inside script

Tags: bash, scripts

In a shell script I tried to replace blank space by \n with this command

```
echo -e $var |tr ' ' '\n'
```

Outside the script it workd perfectly but inside there is no effect .
This how i use in the script:

```
var =$(echo -e $var | tr ' ' '\n' )
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After expanding a parameter expansion (`$var`) or command substitution (`$(cmd)`), the shell removes all whitespace from the expanded result in order to split them into words (word splitting). On top of that, it tries to match filenames for the words that contain `*`, `?` and/or `[...]` (pathname expansion). So **always** enclose expansions in double quotes (`"$var"` and `"$(cmd)"`) to avoid word splitting and pathname expansion to be attempted.

```
$ var=$'two\nlines   here'
$ echo $var
two lines here
$ echo "$var"
two
lines   here
$
```

Hence:

```
echo "$var" | tr ' ' '\n'
# or using bash's more powerful types of parameter expansions
echo "${var// /$'\n'}"

var="$(echo "$var" | tr ' ' '\n')"
```

See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 1):

From the Bash manual (`man bash`):

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the
>   command name.  There are two forms:
>
> $(command)
>
> or
>
> `command`
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing `command` and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard output of  the  command, **with
>   any trailing newlines deleted**.

That's why the newline characters are lost.